# How to solve the Google Ads problem in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, advertisements, admob

**Step 1**: I'm implementing a Google AdMob using [this link](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start).

**Step 2**: When I import this plugin in unity->build(ios)-> and implement in xcode then  give this error: `'GoogleMobileAds\GoogleMobileAds.h' file not found`

I'm tried [this one for iOS](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download)
but the error is still not solved.

Reference:

[image]

**GoogleMobileAds.h Not Found**

[image]

I'm surfacing this problem the last 3 days - what is the issue with the plugin?

Comment: How to Solve the error, i m trying this error to solve but not solve the error, create a new project and download the plugin official website https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start  and import plugin and build in xcode but give an error `#import  <GoogleMobileAds.h/GoogleMobileAds.h>` not found

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. When possible, please post error messages, code, etc as text rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem when making a build in windows for unity IOS and then porting over to my Mac to build with Xcode. Unity provides a Podfile in it's IOS build to get the Google Ad SDK.

Solution that worked for me:

Open terminal on your Mac
In terminal: sudo gem install cococapods

After it finishes navagate, in terminal, to your project folder.
e.g cd /local/Desktop/

type in: pod update

Wait 15-20 min for this to complete. There is no progress so just be patient.

It will create a Pod folder and download the SDK needed for your build.

Now use the .xcworkspace file it created to open your project from now on. DO NOT USE the old .xcodeproj file. 
If you don't see a Pods section in your hierarchy when you open Xcode then you selected the wrong file.

Comment: thanks...that post saved me hours ;)